# Insert last characters of a value in Postgres table while inserting that same value

Tags: postgresql

**CONTEXT:**
I'm currently building a custom import script in Python with psycopg2 that inserts values from a csv file into a postgres database. The csv however provides me with a value that needs refining.

**PROBLEM:** In the example below you can see what I want:
I want the 5 last digits from the 15-digit.

```
mytestdb=# select * from testtable;
 uid | first_name | last_name | age |         15-digit           | last_5_digits
-----+------------+-----------+-----+----------------------------+-----------------
   1 | John       | Doe       |  42 | 99999999912345             | 12345
```

I know I could accomplish this by first inserting the supplied values (first_name, last_name, age and 15-digit) and then using RIGHT(15-digit,5) and an UPDATE statement fill the last_5_digits field.

I would however prefer to do this during the initial INSERT of the row. This would considerably lower the amount of transactions on the database.

Could anyone help me getting this done?

Comment: I typically do this by first importing the raw data into a staging table (usually defined as `unlogged`) and the massage the data while I am inserting it into the real table.

Comment: As an alternative, you might consider using [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader)  instead

Comment: Do it during load in Python then, `your15digitfield[-5:]` will get you the last 5 characters of a Python string variable.